# Looping Images without GIF's

Tags: processing

Gifs display bad on my dark game background. So I saved all the 21 frames individually. Put them in my data folder. Now I need them to independently loop and at the mouse pressed command to stop looping. How are the code lines to import all of the 21 images and then have them loop and stopped when mouse is being pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Start smaller.

Can you write a little example sketch that loads a single image and displays it? Take a look at the loadImage() reference here: https://www.processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html

Can you then expand that little example sketch to show two images that alternate when you press the mouse? Can you add a delay between the switching so you can see each image?

Then can you expand *that* little example sketch to show all 21 images? The ArrayList reference might be useful to you: https://www.processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html

When you get stuck on one of those little example sketches, post it as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a specific question, and we'll go from there.